# Change posts_per_page Into MySQL Query for WooCommerce AJAX Live Search

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, woocommerce

Using posts_per_page might not be the best option and I'm wondering if it should be changed into a MySQL query to be quicker and add less stress to site / server?

This is a process for building a live product search for WooCommerce.

**This is the code:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch' );
function data_fetch() {

    $post_search_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['search_keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );

    if( $post_search_query->have_posts() ) :
        
        while( $post_search_query->have_posts() ): $post_search_query->the_post(); ?>
            
            <h5><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
            <span class="live-search-post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>

            <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    die();
}
```

**Whereof I'm wondering if there's a way to change this:**

```
$post_search_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['search_keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
```

**into an SQL query and if so - how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wpdb.

```
global $wpdb;

$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Comment: Ok, good to know - thanks. Any examples on how to get all products from that?

Comment: You can check database tables I think the product on woo is on wp_posts table with post_type = "product"

Comment: Or by using this "SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type = 'product' and post_title like '%'.esc_attr( $_POST['search_keyword'] ).'%'"

Comment: Your welcome if this answer helps you I am more gratetful if you click the "Accept this answer" Good day ^_^.

Comment: I will as soon as I test it out.

Comment: I changed it accordingly to what you suggested in your comment. This is the new argument: 

`$post_search_query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type = 'product' and post_title like '%'.esc_attr( $_POST['search_keyword'] ).'%'");`

I then get this error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

If you know how to fix that, then I guess that's it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type = 'product' and post_title like '%'".esc_attr( $_POST['search_keyword'] )."'%'"`

Comment: That removed the error, but the search is dead. Nothing shows up. Not sure why.

Comment: You need to change also the loop.. you can use normal for loop or foreach so that you can display the data.

Comment: Ah, okay. Being a beginner at all of this, I'm still learning. I know there's a rule here whereof "1 question.." and what not. Thanks for your time. I'll ask a new question about the loop (unless you feel like helping).